# Does "the 4th place" need "in" before it?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> "Our company is the largest steel manufacture in the U.S. and the 4th
>   place in the world."

Should I put *"in"* front of the 4th place?
The first sentence is SVC. Our company = manufacture.
The second sentence should be the same structure as SVC, so it should be "Our company = the 4th place" or "in the 4th place"? Or, it doesn't have to be SVC? I would like to use the word "Place" or "position"in the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

First - *manufacturer*, not *manufacture*. *manufacturer* is the noun; *manufacture* is the verb. Here's how I would phrase this to sound better:

> "Our company is the largest steel manufacturer in the U.S. and the fourth largest in the world."

You already say "Our company is the largest...in the U.S." in the first part of the sentence so it makes sense to use a parallel structure to describe the company's rank in the world. Why complicate things by using additional words like "place" or "position" (or "rank")?

Answer (score 0):

I would just say:

> Our company is the largest steel manufacture**r** in the United States and the **4th largest in the world.**

Now considering that you want to add the word "Place" or "position" in the sentence. you can as an alternative say:

> Our company is the largest steel manufacturer in the United States and occupy the 4th **place** as the largest in the world.

Or also:

> Our company **occupy the first place** as the largest steel manufacturer in the United States and the 4th **place** as the largest in the world.

Comment: Both of your uses of **occupy** are wrong. The subject is singular, so you need to **occupies**. But, worse, you can't say *occupies the first place as the largest*. You have to instead reverse it and say *among the largest steel manufacturers in the United States, our company occupies first place*. (Also dropping the article.)